# Is there a way to run GCP's Cloud Run with Private GKE cluster?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, istio, google-cloud-run, google-anthos

I understand there are two ways in which a container can be deployed on Google Cloud Run:

1. ***Cloud Run Fully managed***: This runs independently managed by GCP without us creating a cluster
2. ***Cloud Run for Anthos***: This needs us to create a GKE cluster with Cloud Run enable

I want to go for the second option but would like to keep the GKE cluster private so that no external traffic is allowed.

All the documentation and resources I am going through are explaining everything with Public GKE Clusters (with external IPs).

Is there a way to achieve what I am looking for?

What problems will I face while doing the setup?

Is istio always necessary when using Cloud Run with GKE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can deploy Cloud Run on GKE in private mode (not really easy to found in documentation, [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/run/deploy#--connectivity) the link to the gcloud command line).

If the connectivity is private, the service will be reachable only from inside the cluster, and not from internet.

I don't figure what problem you can have for the set up.

Finally, Knative is based on Istio. You can't deploy Knative element without it. And Cloud Run on GKE is simply a package of Knative product by Google. (For managed is different)

Comment: Every time I try to deploy a service, I get an error saying `Failed to create a service. Tracking number: 1some2thing3random`.  You have any idea why?

Comment: Do you have more information in logs? What's the full config of your cluster?

Comment: I have asked another question about this issue. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58115936/gcp-cloud-run-failed-to-create-a-service) is the link. I have explained everything in the question in detail. Please have a look