# GCP Cloud Run: Failed to create a service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, istio, google-cloud-run, knative

I am trying to use Cloud run with private GKE cluster.
I created the cluster using the below command:

```
gcloud beta container clusters create cluster-name \
    --create-subnetwork name=cloud-run-subnet \
    --enable-master-authorized-networks \
    --enable-ip-alias \
    --enable-private-nodes \
    --enable-private-endpoint \
    --master-ipv4-cidr 172.16.0.32/28 \
    --no-enable-basic-auth \
    --no-issue-client-certificate \
    --addons=HorizontalPodAutoscaling,HttpLoadBalancing,Istio,CloudRun \
    --machine-type=n1-standard-1 \
    --enable-stackdriver-kubernetes \
    --scopes cloud-platform \
    --zone us-central1-a
```

I created a bastion host in the same VPC and subnet that can contact this cluster using the below command:

```
gcloud compute instances create bastion \
 --zone us-central1-a \
 --subnet cloud-run-subnet \
 --machine-type=g1-small \
 --scopes cloud-platform
```

I installed kubectl on the bastion host and switched the context to this cluster using `gcloud container clusters get-credentials` command.

I made sure Istio is enabled on default namespace using the below command:

```
kubectl label namespace default istio-injection=enabled
```

Now when I try to deploy a service using the below command I get an error:

```
gcloud beta run deploy hello \
    --image=gcr.io/projectname/hello-world \
    --platform=gke \
    --cluster=cluster-name \
    --cluster-location=us-central1-a \
    --connectivity=internal
```

**Error:**

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.run.deploy) Error:                                                                                                                                                                             
failed calling webhook "webhook.serving.knative.dev": Post https://webhook.knative-serving.svc:443/?timeout=30s: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting he
aders)
```

I tried with both `--connectivity=internal` and `--connectivity=external` I get the same error.

When I try to create the service using the console, I get the following error:

```
Failed to create a service

Tracking number: d123456789
```

I have made sure to keep the same project for the container registry (*gcr.io*) and GKE cluster.

Exact things work fine with public clusters.
I am not able to find specific documentation to get it all working with private GKE cluster. Is there anything that I am missing?
Is there anything that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

A similar issue was fixed doing that in this GitHub thread:

https://github.com/knative/serving/issues/4868

The main cause is that in a private GKE cluster, by default only the GKE master have access to the services at port 443 or 80.

---

Could you try to use the port `8443` instead of the `443`, and white-list the port `8443`.

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#add_firewall_rules

Comment: Thanks for the note. I am a bit busy with other tasks now, I will give this a try and let you know if it worked in a few days.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to deploy Cloud Run service with yaml file?

Here the file

```
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1alpha1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello
  namespace: default
spec:
  traffic:
  - percent: 100
    latestRevision: true
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/projectname/hello-world
```

Simply perform a `kubectl apply -f <file>` from your bastion

If it works, this means that gcloud command can't communicate with a private cluster (and you can open an issue on this).

Comment: Nope. This doesn't work, it gives `Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "knative.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "webhook.serving.knative.dev": Post https://webhook.knative-serving.svc:443/?timeout=30s: dial tcp xx.xx.x.xx:8443: i/o timeout
` I tried for both private and public clusters. It works fine for public clusters and fails for the private one.

Comment: K8S is sometime mysterious... Sorry but my skills end here. And I never managed a private cluster like this. I upvote your question, it is really interesting